# 3-d reconstruction (z-stack) of individual eps files (each of them a slice along the xy plane)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, inkscape

I would like to create a z-stack of several individual eps files, each of them being actually a slice along the xy-plane..

What is the easiest way to do this and the easiest software to use (preferrably a freeware one)?

Thank you in advance,
AV

p.s: In particular, I am interested in knowing to perform a 3-d reconstruction on a single image, using individual already pre-acquired images where each individual one is an xy slice...

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Unfortunately, it is unclear what you want to do. Do you want to create an image such as [this](http://bioimagel.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/images/stack.333130145.jpg) or do you want to make an animation or do you just want to tile your sub-images?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. In fact, I would like to be able to know to do each option:

Comment: if I could more specify, what I would in particular like to know is a 3-d reconstruction, as shown here (Fig.S2,lower line the 3rd panel from right): http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/marc.201200322/asset/supinfo/marc_201200322_sm_suppl.pdf?v=1&s=36b5383aeb66bef0b185e53d5a0ff13e78c5d08c

Comment: if I could more specify, what I would in particular like to know is a 3-d reconstruction, as shown here (Fig.S2,lower line the 3rd panel from right): http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/marc.201200322/asset/supinfo/marc_201200322_sm_suppl.pdf?v=1&s=36b5383aeb66bef0b185e53d5a0ff13e78c5d08c

Comment: Its actually not a stack of eps images but a render of a heightmap or a voxel representation. Neither inkscape nor illustrator are particulary well suited for this.

Comment: sorry, I mean the 3rd panel starting from left, in the lower line (i.e. the far-right-most image)

Comment: Yes, i kindof understood that. Still not a stack, probably a voxel render.

Comment: in fact, also knowing how to easily perform what was nicely suggested by wrzlprmft below (http://bioimagel.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/images/stack.333130145.jpg) would be of much help...to me, this array of figures looks similar to the 3-d reconstruction shown here (Fig.S2, lower panel, far right): http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/marc.201200322/asset/supinfo/marc_201200322_sm_suppl.pdf?v=1&s=36b5383aeb66bef0b185e53d5a0ff13e78c5d08c

Comment: Thanx, jooja! Adding to mz last comment, I consider the two images in each of the two links being processed similarly, where somehow the distance between the individual slices (slices along the xy plane) differs... would be great to know how to adjust this distance, in addition!

Comment: If thats what you want then sure no problem.

Comment: I would be grateful, joojaa,if you can provide any hints (way, software) for a voxel rendering process..Hopefully without involving scripting generation!

Answer (score 1):

The image in question is most likely a height map or voxel render. It is offcourse also possible to stack eps images but to pull a good effect you would need alpha and EPS does not contain any such thing. Stacking nonetheless is easy.

[image: Sliced voxel image]

**Image 1:** A sliced voxel image rendered in Mathematica, sampe data of same program.